Some errors in my formulas I can't find about $\frac1z$
I'm trying to prove that if you do a symmetry wrt to $$Z=0$$ of the Riemann sphere, you obtain $$z\mapsto \frac1z$$(illustration from here)

So, I put the sphere like this (illustration from wikipedia) 
In $\mathbb R^3$, let $N=(0,0,1)$ and $A=(x,y,0)$. then $\vec{NA}=A-N=(x,y,-1)$. Let $\xi\in \mathbb R$ such that $N+\xi \vec{NA}\in S\doteq \{(X,Y,Z): X^2+Y^2+Z^2=1\}$ $$N+\xi\vec{NA}=(0,0,1)+\xi (x,y,-1)=(\xi x,\xi y,1-\xi)$$ $$||N+\xi \vec{NA}||^2=\xi^2 x^2+\xi^2 y^2+(1-\xi )^2=\xi^2(x^2+y^2+1)-2\xi+1$$Then $$\xi= \frac{2}{1+[z|^2}$$with $z=x+iy$
Then $$P(z)=(0,0,1)+\frac{2}{1+|z|^2}(\mathcal {Re}z,\mathcal {Im}z,-1)$$ $$\boxed{P(z)=\frac{2}{1+|z|^2}(\mathcal {Re}z,\mathcal {Im}z,-1+|z|^2)}$$Then my idea is to calculate with this formula $P(\frac 1z)$ and I find $\frac{2}{1+|z|^2}(\mathcal{Re}z,-\mathcal{Im}z,-1+|z|^2)$

But first, $P(0)=(0,0,-2)\neq (0,0,-1)!!!$
And secondly my result with $P(\frac1z)$ does not allow me to conclude because symmetry is  $$(X,Y,Z)\to (X,Y,-Z)$$

Please help.

First, $$ \boxed{\forall z\in\mathbb C,P(z)=\frac{2}{1+|z|^2}(\mathcal {Re}z,\mathcal {Im}z,\frac{-1+|z|^2)}{\color{red}2}}$$Secondly $$\forall z\in \mathbb C^*, P(\frac{1}{\color{red}{\bar z}})=Sym(P(z))$$with $Sym:(X,Y,Z)\mapsto (X,Y,-Z)$
It is not $z\mapsto \frac1z$ as suggested in the film, but $$z\mapsto \frac{1}{   \color{red}{ \bar z}  }$$which IS NOT a Möbius transformation of the form $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, which is exclusively a priori in question in the film

Yes. Expressed in polar form,  we see that if $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $\frac 1z = \frac 1re^{-i\theta}$, which maps points in the upper half-plane to points in the lower half-plane and vice versa. But stereographic projection maps the upper half-plane to the half-sphere with $y > 0$, and reflection through the plane $z=0$ preserves that half-sphere, meaning that the projection-reflection-inverse-projection combination maps the upper half-plane to itself, so it cannot be the inverse. You need to reflect through the $x$-axis, not the $xy$-plane.
